# When I try to read a double from keyboard it only accepts when it's separerat with a comma

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, numeric-input

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double cost = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(cost);
```

So i try writing 7.6 and it throws and exception in main. But when i write 7,6 it's OK and it prints 7.6

I'm using eclipse as my IDE

Comment: Eclipse is hardly issue, so I removed that tag from your question.

Answer (score 2):

System locale uses decimal separator `','` (on your current system), you can explicitly specify the locale the scanner should use like

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.useLocale(Locale.US);
double cost = scan.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MWiWa Happy to help. Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the *complimentary* (that means **free**) [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).